# How to track the state of a window toggle with python?

Tags: python, scripting

With bpy I can call the following function:

```
bpy.ops.wm.window_fullscreen_toggle()
```

But how can I track the state of the toggle so that I avoid unnecessary calls to the bpy.ops.wm.window_fullscreen_toggle() function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the code

```
size = bpy.context.window.y
if size == 0:
     # it's fullscreen
else:
     # it's not fullscreen
```

I don't know if that's the proper way to do it, but it works for me

Comment: Will depend on screen setup.  My desktop has only a title bar across the top with a height of 64.  In full screen window y reports as -64 and in max (but not full) as 64.  It's been my experience that blenders `window.y` is dodgy on ubuntu. On toggling out of full screen it sometimes reports as 250 instead.  Found this out trying to overlay a decoration free window over a particular area type. (Text editor).

Answer (score 5):

**Third party window manager.**

*This may have changed  AFAIK there is no property exposed akin to `Window.is_full_screen` in blender.  Have resorted to using a third party window manager.*

[Get Monitor Resolution in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129322/how-do-i-get-monitor-resolution-in-python)

Example run on old monitor where 1200 x 1024 is full  screen resolution.

Can get blenders context  window height and width via

```
>>> C.window.height
1024
```

or loop over all windows in `C.window_manager.windows`

I'm on ubuntu and have the lightweight `ewmh` window manager module available.  The Gtk `gi` is another I often use for managing windows (focusing, moving workspace, making thumbnails etc)

Running from blender the current window is the active window.

```
>>> from ewmh import EWMH
>>> wm = EWMH()
>>> win = wm.getActiveWindow()
>>> win.get_wm_class()
('Blender', 'Blender')
```

Check its geometry

```
>>> win.get_geometry()
<<class 'Xlib.protocol.request.GetGeometry'> serial = 15, data = {'depth': 24, 'sequence_number': 15, 'root': <<class 'Xlib.display.Window'> 0x0000028e>, 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'width': 1280, 'height': 1024, 'border_width': 0}, error = None>
```

Or query its states

```
>>> wm.getWmState(win, True)
['_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN', '_NET_WM_STATE_FOCUSED']
```

Ok looks like in full screen, run the op

```
>>> bpy.ops.wm.window_fullscreen_toggle()
{'FINISHED'}

>>> wm.getWmState(win, True)
['_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ', '_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT', '_NET_WM_STATE_FOCUSED']
```

Probably worth mentioning, since I am using a window manager can do away with using the operator.

```
>>> wm.setWmState(
setWmState(self, win, action, state, state2=0)
Set/unset one or two state(s) for the given window (property
_NET_WM_STATE).
:param win: the window object
:param action: 0 to remove, 1 to add or 2 to toggle state(s)
:param state: a state
:type state: int or str (see :attr:`NET_WM_STATES`)
:param state2: a state or 0
:type state2: int or str (see :attr:`NET_WM_STATES`)
```

So to set full screen using `ewmh`

```
>>> wm.setWmState(win, 1, '_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN')
>>> wm.display.flush()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Too bad the blender doesn't have a built-in property

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu users:

```
import bpy
import subprocess

monitor_width,monitor_height = subprocess.Popen('xrandr | grep "\*" | cut -d" " -f4',shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split(b'x')

if(int(monitor_width)==bpy.context.window.width and int(monitor_height)==bpy.context.window.height):
    print("fullscreen")
else:
    print("not fullscreen")
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597965/getting-monitor-resolution-in-python-on-ubuntu)